# Converting data between classes in R: large CSV file, prices recorded like "$10.00"

Tags: r, csv

So full disclosure, I am new to R and programming in general. Because of that, it is very hard for me to search when I have problems because I am not even sure what keywords to use. I am learning, and all I am hoping for y'all to do is point me in the right direction.

I have a very large csv file that I imported into R. Around 2 million observations (don't worry, I am not planning on using all 2 million). The only problem is that the people recording the data formatted the file to record to prices as "$10.00". Because of this, R recognizes the data has a factor, and also treats each individual price as a separate variable because of the dollar sign. I would like to reformat this column as a numeric variable.

I am sure there is some way to go about reformatting this in R, the only problem is I am not sure which functions I need. Sorry for the very basic question, I have just hit a wall a figured I would reach out.

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your data looks like this:

```
x<-c("$10.00","$11.24","$15.22")
```

You can use the *substring* function to trim the initial dollar sign (which will still leave you with strings) and then use *as.numeric* to turn it to a numeric vector.

```
newx<-as.numeric(substring(x,2))
```

will produce a vector named *newx* with value

```
c(10.00,11.24,15.22)
```

We tell the substring to start at the 2nd character (strings in R are 1-indexed), and then cast to numeric.

---

In your data frame (suppose it is called `df`), you can replace the column like

```
df$MoneyColumn <- as.numeric(substring(df$MoneyColumn,2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

We could also use `sub`

```
as.numeric(sub('\\D+', '', x))
#[1] 10.00 11.24 15.22
```

#### data

```
x<-c("$10.00","$11.24","$15.22")
```